# Scala passing varargs to another function that takes varargs

Tags: scala

Why `varargs` can't be passed as another `varargs` without `:_*` ?

```
object Main {

  def main(s: Array[String]): Unit = {


    def someFunction(varars: String*) = {
      someOtherFunction(varars) // Compilation ERRRO 
      someOtherFunction(varars:_*) // Works, but why ?  
    }

    def someOtherFunction(someOtherVarars: String*): Unit = {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `varars` is a single argument - an array of strings (note, that I'm not writing `Array[String]`, because it is not **the** java `Array`, more details [here](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11024#issuecomment-406206180)), whereas by looking at the signature `def someOtherFunction(someOtherVarars: String*): Unit`, we can tell, that `someOtherFunction` takes multiple arguments of type `String` each. You cannot simply pass an array as the parameter to `someOtherFunction`, you need to "unfold" it first.

In other words an argument can be passed to `someOtherFunction` it has to be marked as a sequence argument. It would not make much sense to be able to pass `varargs` and `varargs(1)` to the single function. It's described in [SLS §4.6.2](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Comment: My IDE tells me that `varars` is type `Seq[String]` and, indeed, `val arr:Array[String] = varars` won't compile.

Comment: @jwvh it's of type `WrappedArray[String]`

Comment: 2.13 has deprecated `WrappedArray[_]` in favor of `ArraySeq[_]` but, in fact, neither of those assignments will compile.

Comment: @jwvh you might be interested in this thread, especially comment https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11024#issuecomment-407463955

Comment: Interesting indeed. Thank you. But the whole thread is about how to handle arrays, and other mutable collections, when passed to a varags method. [This post](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11024#issuecomment-406206180) in particular mentions the Array -> Seq _conversion_. My point stands: varargs are not _recieved_ as Arrays.

Comment: @jwvh ok, I understand now, I didn't know how to capture that in words. I have written an array, not `Array` not to indicate it's **the** `Array` wrapping over java. As you noticed, the type changes with time

Comment: Few upvotes for such a good explanation and reference.

Answer (score 4):

"varargs"parameter means it can take any number of strings as an argument(i.e., a varargs field).

> def someFunction(varars: String*): Seq[String] = {
>       varars   }

if you define the above method and check for type of "varars" it has now become Seq[String] when you are using it. But when you pass it to another method which is expecting variableArgs type. It mismatch as it has become Seq[String] which should be converted to variable arguments using (someOtherVarars: _*).

_* operator tells the compiler to pass each element of the sequence as a separate argument, instead of passing it as a single argument.

Comment: Maybe I understand you wrong, but you're saying, that both argument in signature and argument passed are of type `Seq[String]`. Wouldn't it mean it should compile?

Comment: According to question, varars of "def someFunction(varars: String*)" has become Seq[String] when it is passed to someOtherFunction(varars) whereas someOtherFunction expects variable argument. thats why _* is needed to convert Seq[String] to String*.